# Why Hibernate executeUpdate is very slow?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

We explicitly set character-set `utf8mb4` before every transaction in Hibernate by calling `SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'`. When we execute it by creating sql query and it take 30 ~ 40 seconds.

```
try {
    Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
    Transaction tr = session.getTransaction();
    tr.begin();

    // logged start time
    session.createSQLQuery("SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'").executeUpdate();
    // logged end time.


    // execute other Hibernate queries
}catch(...){....}
```

What could be the reason behind taking time much time? As it doesn't require any table access.